# Can you display integers in a list that are greater than an initial value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print values in a list, that are integers, that are greater than a set initial value, which is also an integer. Would I need a slice to do this?

Here is my code:

```
n = 3

num_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

empty_array = []

if any(n > x for n in num_array):
        empty_array.append(x)
    
print(empty_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote doesn't work because:

1. You're telling it to `append` `x` (which doesn't exist outside the generator expression) if at least one value in `num_array` passes the test given, so any passing value would `append` only once, not append *all* the passing values, and
2. The test is nonsensical (you've never assigned to `x`, and you're shadowing the definition of `n` from outside the genexpr with a new one inside it; I'm guessing you intended `for x in num_array`, not `for n in num_array`, but since neither work, it's largely irrelevant)

Slicing doesn't help (it's done with index ranges, not value tests, though `numpy` does offer a solution similar to slicing if you're using it). The typical solution would be a list comprehension (listcomp):

```
new_array = [x for x in num_array if x > n]
```

or if you insist on making an empty `list` and populating it element by element:

```
new_array = []
for x in num_array:
    if x > n:
        new_array.append(x)
```

If you were using `numpy`, you could do this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3

num_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

new_array = num_array[num_array > n]
```

to get a syntax reminiscent of slicing, but Python built-in types don't support bulk vectorized operations and masking like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension here:

```py
n = 3
num_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
empty_array = [x for x in num_array if x > n]
print(empty_array)  # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: This works thank you! But is it possible to do this without list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, you could use a basic loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you wanted?

```
n = 3

num_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
empty_array = []

for i in num_array:
    if n < i: # If 3 is less than the number the loop is on
        empty_array.append(i)
print(empty_array)
```